# "Manuscript submitted for publication" with APA BibLaTeX style

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I use Zotero with Better BibTeX to manage my references. I am trying to reference an article that has been submitted for publication. According to the [APA style guide](https://libguides.jcu.edu.au/apa/what-if#s-lg-box-21191678), the manuscript should be cited with year it was written, and listed in the references with "Manuscript submitted for publication" at the end of the reference.

I have tried to follow the instructions in section 4.2.1 of the APA BibLaTeX style documentation, but either I am doing something wrong or it doesn't work. Adding `pubstate = {mansub}` to the bib entry correctly displays "Manuscript submitted for publication" at the end of the reference. However if I also give the year, then "Manuscript submitted for publication" is omitted from the reference.

MWE:

main.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{english-apa}


\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\cite{matherIntraplateVolcanismTriggered2020}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

references.bib

```
@article{matherIntraplateVolcanismTriggered2020,
  title = {Intraplate Volcanism Triggered by Bursts in Slab Flux},
  author = {Mather, Ben R. and Müller, R. Dietmar and Seton, Maria and Ruttor, Saskia and Nebel, Oliver and Mortimer, Nick},
  date = {2020-12-16},
  journaltitle = {Science Advances},
  volume = {6},
  number = {51},
  pages = {eabd0953},
  pubstate = {mansub},
  publisher = {{American Association for the Advancement of Science}},
}
```

Comment: Where is the problem coming, is Zotero not generating a bib with `pubstate = {mansub}` if a year is provided, or is biblatex ignoring `pubstate = {mansub}` if there is a year in the bib?  The latter is a good question for us but it would significantly help if you can provide a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) to demonstrate the issue, if it's the former you may be better off asking Zotero/Better Bibtex.

Comment: That's a good point, Zotero isn't really responsible here as far as I can tell. Edited question for clarity and MWE.

Comment: `\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{english-apa}` hasn't been necessary for `biblatex-apa` since about November 2017. You should be able to drop it now.

Comment: If `biblatex-apa` produces output that goes against APA guidance, please open a bug report at https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues. (Posting a question on a forum does not alert the developers of packages automatically. So the problem might remain unfixed.) Do note though that the APA style guidance you cited is from a third party and not official APA guidance. It also links to a version of the (old) APA style blog for 6th-edition APA style. The current APA version is the 7th edition.

Answer (score 1):

`pubstate` is available as an alternative to supplying a year in citations and bibliography, manuscript submitted is not appearing as an additional item in the bibliography entry but in place of the year. If a year is available that is used and so `pubstate` is suppressed.

Instead the `howpublished` field also supports `mansub` and adds an additional item in the bibliography entry indicating that the manuscript has been submitted for publication.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@unpublished{a,
  title = {Title},
  author = {Author, A.},
  journaltitle = {Journal},
  date = {2023},
  pubstate = {mansub},
  howpublished = {mansub},
}
@unpublished{b,
  title = {Title},
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  date = {2023},
  howpublished = {mansub},
}
@unpublished{c,
  title = {Title},
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  howpublished = {mansub},
  pubstate = {mansub},
}
@unpublished{d,
  title = {Title},
  author = {Duthor, D.},
  pubstate = {mansub},
}
@unpublished{e,
  title = {Title},
  author = {Euthor, E.},
  howpublished = {mansub},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{a,b,c,d,e}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

> Author, 2023; Buthor, 2023; Cuthor, manuscript submitted for publication;
> Duthor, manuscript submitted for publication; Euthor, n.d.
>
> ### References
>
> Author, A. (2023). Title [Manuscript submitted for publication].
>
> Buthor, B. (2023). Title [Manuscript submitted for publication].
>
> Cuthor, C. (manuscript submitted for publication). Title [Manuscript submitted
>
> for publication].
>
> Duthor, D. (manuscript submitted for publication). Title.
>
> Euthor, E. (n.d.). Title [Manuscript submitted for publication].

Note while this all carries over to `@article`, you most likely want to be using `@unpublished` (in Zotero this would mean setting Item Type to *Manuscript* rather than *Journal Article*) which doesn't expect a `journaltitle`.